# If statements with python 3.3

Tags: python

```
correct = input("Is this correct audio?")
if input = "yes":        
stream.stop_stream()
```

eclipse tells me `:` is expected but I don't understand why its saying that

Comment: Did you forget correct indentation?

Comment: What happened to your indentation? It's pretty essential in Python so make sure to paste it exactly correctly.

Comment: You'll also want to use `==` instead of `=` in the conditional.

Comment: You cannot assign in a condition in Python, do you really have `if input = "yes":`?

Comment: indentation is normal, it seems off from here cause of the way I pasted the code on here

Comment: The reason eclipse is telling you `:` is expected is that the thing between `if` and `:` has to be an expression. `input = "yes"` isn't an expression, but `input` is. So, eclipse is guessing that you meant `if input:`. (It doesn't always guess right…)

Comment: Meanwhile, on top of the other two problems, you probably wanted to compare `correct`, not `input`. `input` is a function, and a function is never equal to the string `"yes"`. `correct` is the string returned by that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three problems here:

- You need to use `==` to compare values, not `=`. In Python, `=` is only for assignment statements, not comparison expressions.
- You need to indent the block underneath the `if` line.
- You need to compare `correct`, not `input`. `input` is a function, and no function is equal to the string `"yes"`. But `correct` is the string you got back from calling that function, and that *will* be equal to the string `"yes"` (as long as that's what the user typed, of course).

The error you're getting is from the first mistake.

The `if` condition—the part between the keyword `if` and the `:`—has to be an expression. But `input = "yes"` isn't an expression; it's a statement. That's an error. But eclipse is trying to guess what you really meant. `input = "yes"` may not be an expression, but `input` by itself is, so it guesses you meant `if input:`. It guessed wrong, but hey, points for trying, right?

If you fix that `SyntaxError`, you'll next get an `IndentationError`, which is pretty obvious to understand and to fix.

If you fix that, the last one is harder to debug. There's no error, it's just that the comparison is always false, no matter what you type. You can drive yourself crazy trying to figure out if there are newlines you need to strip or some other weird thing you've neglected before noticing a simple mistake like this…

So:

```
correct = input("Is this correct audio?")
if correct == "yes":
    stream.stop_stream()
```